# select with multiple conditions from table with one to many relations

Tags: sql

I've got several tables that looks like this

```
-- TablePair
pairId ID value
 p1    1  'val1'
 p2    2  'val2'
 p3    3  'val3'
 p4    4  'val4'
```

Also I've got a table that references to that table

```
-- TableObject
objectId refId
   ob1     p1 
   ob1     p2
   ob1     p3
   ob2     p3
```

I want to select only object that has `1 = val1, 2 = val2, 3)` and value `('val1', 'val2', 'val3')`. In our case it would be only object `ob1`. In other cases it should return nothing.

When I do like this

```
select objectId from TablePair
    inner join TableObject
where (id = '1' and value = 'val1')
    or (id = '2' and value = 'val2')
    or (id = '3' and value = 'val3')
```

It returns same three objects. I add `distinct` and it returns fine. 
But if I have at least one condition working it still returns the object. But I want to return nothing in that case.

How to do that? (it should DMS agnostic)

The expected result should for `ob1`

```
1 'val1'
2 'val2'
3 'val3'
```

because it references to that `pairId` in `TableObject`.
For `ob2` it should return `null` as `ob2` references only to one condition

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want it to be agnostic (in my case it should work `h2`, `postgresql`)

Comment: use `and` instead of `or`

Comment: Try `select objectId from TablePair
    inner join TableObject
where (id = '1' and value = 'val1')
    and (id = '2' and value = 'val2')
    and (id = '3' and value = 'val3')` may just work.

Comment: with `and` it returns null for `ob1`

Comment: I wanted to use (id, value) in ((,)) but it does not work in `h2`

Comment: See https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/ for general sql options

Comment: You need a join for each condition and then use `and`

Comment: `select objectId from TableObject
where COUNT(*) = 3 groupby objectId;` hoping this will work.

Comment: Can you provide expected result from your sample data? Your text is not clear.

Comment: @Viki888 added expected result

Comment: @user1432980 What if there is another record in `TableObject` like `ob1  p4`? In this case also, does Ob1 have to return the above result?

Comment: @Viki888 it does not matter

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

```
SELECT tp.ID, tp.value
FROM TablePair tp
JOIN TableObject tob ON tp.pairId = tob.refId
JOIN (SELECT ObjectId
        FROM TablePair tp
        JOIN TableObject tob ON tp.pairId = tob.refId
        WHERE (id = '1' AND value = 'val1')
            OR (id = '2' AND value = 'val2')
            OR (id = '3' AND value = 'val3')
        GROUP BY objectId HAVING COUNT(1) = 3) tF 
    ON tF.ObjectId = tob.ObjectId
WHERE (tp.id = '1' AND tp.value = 'val1')
    OR (tp.id = '2' AND tp.value = 'val2')
    OR (tp.id = '3' AND tp.value = 'val3');
```

The above query gave me below result even though if there is a record in `TableObject` like `ob1 p4`,

[image]

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: I decided to use @jackjay approach but adjusted it to use `group by objectId having (count(*) = 3)`